# sed substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, ksh

I have a string as follows:

```
/test/test/ 12 /test/test
```

My goal is to turn it into:

```
/test/est/ 12 /test/test
```

This is the command:

```
echo "$x" | sed 's@\(/*/\).@\1@g'"
```

I am using at the moment but it is applying it everywhere instead of at the second instance of "/"

Comment: could you please update your post and show us what is your string and what you want as a result ? Its unclear.

Comment: g means global - everywhere

Comment: If you have GNU sed, you can replace just the nth match explicitly e.g. `sed 's@/.@/@2'`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by steeldriver, if you use GNU sed, you can tell which occurrence should be replaced, e.g.:

```
echo "/test/test/ 12 /test/test" | sed -n -e  's_/._/_2 p'
```

If you can not make use of this feature you can also write:

```
echo "/test/test/ 12 /test/test" | sed -n -r -e  's_(/[a-z]([a-z]+))\1_\1/\2_ p'
```

Biliography: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html [*Using \1 to keep part of the pattern*]

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/test/test/ 12 /test/test" | sed 's/\/test\/t/\/test\//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and easy...

```
sed -n "s/test/est/2p"
```

- -n don't print anything
- s/ substitute
- "test" with "est"
- /2 but only the second instance
- p print the results